# Windows 10 Enterprise - Keyboard Func KB-460 - Can't use Windows Key

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

I'm using the `Func KB-460` keyboard and I just reinstalled my computer for the first time in a while. Entering Windows I noticed that the Windows key did not work and that the `Func Mode™` led is active. You can see the led that I mean in the image below to the right.

[image]

This `Func Mode™` apparently disables the Windows key for gaming mode and I can't find any way to deactivate it. Started looking for their software but it seems they wen't bust. Anyone got an idea what I can do about it?

http://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/func-kb450-keyboard-review,1.html

**Update:**

If anyone is as blind as me, <kbd>Fn</kbd> is between <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Menu key</kbd> to the right.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like [Fnatic](https://fnatic.com/gear) purchased Func, though I don't know if they continue to support Func products or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> activates and deactivates Func mode.

Since it seems you may not have the manual for this keyboard, here are some other keybinds you might find useful:

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> will change between Profiles. This might not be useful if you do not have the Settings software installed.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd>/<kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> will adjust the backlight brightness/mode.

Source: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/805635/Func-Kb-460.html#manual

Comment: Thanks, I just found it before you posted. For some reason I was only looking at the keys to the left.

Comment: @Ogglas Good stuff! :)